# Const instead of var for function-scoped variables?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I've been reading about the [Principle of Least Privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege) and am confused when to use `let` vs. `var` vs. `const`, specifically in function-level scope.

I [read](https://davidwalsh.name/for-and-against-let) that:

> Use `let` in places you know you need block scoping, and you've specifically thought about those implications. But continue to use `var` for variables that either cannot easily be block scoped, or which shouldn't be block scoped. There are going to be places in real world code where some variables are going to be properly scoped to the entire function, and for those variables, `var` is a better signal.

Can `const` be used of `var` for function-scoped variables? For example:

```
function foo() {
    const a = 10;

    if (a > 2) {
        let b = a * 3;
        console.log(b);
    }

    if (a > 5) {
        let c = a / 2;
        console.log(c);
    }

    console.log(a);
}
```

Instead of:

```
function foo() {
    var a = 10;

    if (a > 2) {
        let b = a * 3;
        console.log(b);
    }

    if (a > 5) {
        let c = a / 2;
        console.log(c);
    }

    console.log(a);
}
```

Comment: Yes, you just can't modify it

Comment: Yes, you can do like that

Comment: Note that this article is slightly outdated. Now most programmers agree that you should *never* use `var`; instead, you should use `const` if you don't reassign the variable and `let` in if you do.

Comment: I've read various suggestions on this, and some people believe that you might as well just replace var with const as this will prevent any changing of the variable accidentally in other parts of the application code, and use let when you need to modify the variables values. Of course you hear opinions of the other type like what you described above. IMO var is pretty much obsolete, as I use let for declaring variables that are mutable and const for non-mutables, it just helps cut down on coding errors, which I think is a plus. If you work on a development team, they may have their own rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the above code, `const` should be used instead of `var` or `let` because you are using the variable `a` for outputting **new variables** (`b` & `c`) and not manipulating or changing the variable `a` itself. So in other words, the value 'a' remains constant throughout the condition statements.

- **Const:** Use `const` if you don't have to change the value of a variable at all.
- **Let:** Use 'let' if you have to change the value of a variable later.
- **Var:** Avoid using `var` since 'let' has an important scoping mechanism that 'var' doesn't have called **block-scoping**.

> `let` allows you to declare variables that are limited in scope to the
>   block, statement, or expression on which it is used. This is unlike
>   the var keyword, which defines a variable globally, or locally to an
>   entire function regardless of block scope.
>
> Via - [Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)